# How to send results in a for loop one by one from servlet to JSP?

Tags: java, html, jsp, servlets

I am running a set of queries in my servlet(batch processing) using for loop. The problem is I am getting the results in the HTML page(in JSP) once all have been executed. I need to show the result on the the HTML as soon as a query has been executed. How can I send the result one by one to the HTML page?

Comment: use jquery ajax or similar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once you send your response back to your JSP you would need to resend a request to your servlet.
Your best option would be to send a query based request using AJAX for which you would need to redesign your servlet.

Comment: Just downvoting answers helps nobody, please explain

Comment: I am really sorry, this may seem dumb but I am new to this. Do you mean to tell that I have to send the queries one by one from JSP to the servlet, get it executed and then display the result?

Comment: Yes if you want the results to be shown as soon as the query has been executed, you would need to execute these queries one by one using ajax calls from your jsp page. You could refer to a pagination example where something similar is done. For your reference :-http://theopentutorials.com/examples/java-ee/jsp/pagination-in-servlet-and-jsp/

Comment: Hi, the link you sent is unresponsive. And I'm using spring framework for the tool. The above mentioned suggestion could be implemented for spring mvc too right?